# Unable to sort grouped data on aggregation with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework

I am grouping leads data based on email and phone combination. And after getting the resultant data when I perform sorting data is not sorted either in ascending or descending order but it is sorting randomly. I am using node js and mongodb(mongoose) for achieving this.

I have swapped the positions of $sort operator and even then wrongly sorted results came.

```
return db.model('Lead').aggregate([
      {
        $facet: {
          totalData: [
            { $match: queryObj },
            { $group: { _id: { email: "$email", phone: "$phone" }, count: { $sum: 1 }, leads: { $push: { _id: "$_id", name: "$name", firstName: "$firstName", lastName: "$lastName", email: "$email", project: "$project", list: "$list", assignee: "$assignee", phoneCode: "$phoneCode", phone: "$phone", createdAt: "$createdAt", updatedAt: "$updatedAt", utmSource: "$utmSource", source: "$source", unreadmembers: "$unreadmembers" } } } },
            { $sort: {updatedAt: -1} },
            { $skip: (page - 1) * count },
            { $limit: count }
          ],
          totalCount: [
            { $match: queryObj },
            { $group: { _id: { email: "$email", phone: "$phone" } } },
            { $count: "leadsCount" }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]).collation({ locale: "en" }).allowDiskUse(true).exec((err, leadsData) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error: ", err);
      } else {
        console.log("Data: ", leadsData);
      }
    })
```

I want data to be sorted by updatedAt field. Please help me in fixing this.

Comment: You have `$push`ed the `updatedAt` field inside array in `$group` stage.

Comment: Ok then what to do in this case @Ashh

Comment: With which field (array element) do you want to `$sort` with???  It depends on you.

Comment: Can you provide me the modification that I should do. How to pass array element to $sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In $facet use the limit and skip on top order of aggregation pipeline it will improve the performance of execution.
2. Sort the updatedAt after grouping.

   ```
   { $match: queryObj },
   { $skip: (page - 1) * count },
   { $limit: count }
   { $group: { _id: { email: "$email", phone: "$phone" }, count: { $sum: 1 }, leads: 
      { $push: { _id: "$_id", name: "$name", firstName: "$firstName", lastName: 
      "$lastName", email: "$email", project: "$project", list: "$list", assignee: 
      "$assignee", phoneCode: "$phoneCode", phone: "$phone", createdAt: 
      "$createdAt", updatedAt: "$updatedAt", utmSource: "$utmSource", source: 
       "$source", unreadmembers: "$unreadmembers" } } } 
   },
   ```

   { $sort: { "leads.updatedAt": -1 } }

Comment: I have done what you have said. But still data is not sorted properly. I have added { $sort: {updatedAt: -1} }, before $group.

Comment: Can you please post the actual document before aggregation. So it will helpful to fix the issue.

Comment: {  "_id" : ObjectId("5beec31b7aa50e0233e2208a"),  "project" : ObjectId("5beec1bc7aa50e0233e2207c"), "list" : ObjectId("5beec1bc7aa50e0233e2207d"), "email" : "visal@nikulsan.com",
    "phone" : "9738229056",  "country" : "unitedStates", "ipaddress" : "106.51.64.192 ", "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-11-16T13:16:11.916Z"),
 "user" : ObjectId("5b190d3ca2c0485c5516ca64"), "assignee" : ObjectId("5b190d3ca2c0485c5516ca64"), "phoneCode" : "+1", "utmSource" : "Direct", "firstName" : "Visal Yadav", "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-11-16T13:16:11.916Z") }

Comment: try this, use {$sort:'leads,updatedAt':-1} after grouping